# Finer topologies on a compact Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

If we have such topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ that it is compact and Hausdorff, then we can say that for any other topology $\mathcal{H}$ on $X$ such that $\mathcal{T}\subseteq\mathcal{H}$, the topology $\mathcal{H}$ is Hausdorff but no compact.

Hint: Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$, $(Y,\mathcal{H})$ be such two topological spaces that $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff. If $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous bijective map, then $f$ is a homeomorphism.

I have tried the following but I don't understand the problem:

Suppose that there exists such topological space $\mathcal{H}$ that $\mathcal{T}\subseteq\mathcal{H}$ and $(X,\mathcal{H})$ is compact, then there exist such countable set $C$ that $\overline{C}=X$.

Comment: Here is an example: Consider $X = [0, 1]$ with $\mathcal T$ being the standard topology and $\mathcal H$ the discrete topology. Is there a mistake in your question?

Comment: Consider the identity map from $(X,\mathcal H)$ to $(X,\mathcal T)$.

Comment: @DavidMitra I may be misreading the question, but your hint can be used to show that $\mathcal T$ is compact, not the other way around.

Comment: @AymanHourieh I think the OP wants to show no  topology  on $X$ that is strictly finer than $\mathcal T$ can be compact. This is addressed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328923/compactness-and-strictly-finer-topologies). Is my hint off (if $(X,\mathcal H)$ were compact, the identity would be a homeomorphism, and the two topologies would be the same)?

Comment: @DavidMitra But the question says $\mathcal T \subseteq \mathcal H$, i.e. equality is not ruled out. SHB could you clarify your question?

Comment: This was listed among related questions: [Assume that $(\text{X}, T)$ is compact and Hausdorff. Prove that a comparable but different topological space $(\text{X},T')$ is not.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800452/assume-that-textx-t-is-compact-and-hausdorff-prove-that-a-comparable-bu)

Comment: Do we really need the compactness of the coarser space?

Comment: @Saaqib: It’s not needed to show that $\langle X,\mathscr{H}\rangle$ is Hausdorff, but it *is* needed in order to show that $\langle X,\mathscr{H}\rangle$ is not compact, which is the main point.

Answer (score 5):

Let $ (X, \mathcal {T}) $ a compact Hausdorff space and $\mathcal{H} $ a strictly finer topology $\mathcal{T} $, if we take the identity function $ i$ such that $ i :(X,\mathcal {H}) \to (X, \mathcal {T}) $, this function is continuous because $ \mathcal{T} \varsubsetneq \mathcal {H} $. 
 
  Since $ \mathcal {H} $ is strictly finer than $ \mathcal {T}  $ can take $ C $ closed in $ \mathcal{H} $ is not in $ \mathcal {T}  $. If $ (X, \mathcal {H}) $ was compact would have a compact in $ \mathcal {H}  $, now as $C=i(C) $ is $ C $ would have a compact $ \mathcal{T} $ then $ \mathcal {T} = \mathcal {H} $ which can not be.

am I right?